# How to call jquery function in a class file

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi all I have created a javascript which I want to use in my entire application, so I have created a class which returns string as follows

```
 public static string ShowAlert(string pHeader, string pMessage)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("example1('" + pHeader + "','" + pMessage + "')");
        sb.Append("</Script");
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This is my code `JFunction.JS`

```
(function example1(title, content) {
    $.msgBox({
        title: title,
        content: content
    });
})
```

Now on button click I am just calling as follows

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "",ShowAlert(pHeader,pMessage) , true);`

But I am unable to get the message, so is there any way to create a unique method instead of calling the script on each page,

Comment: Why do you have your CS Method in the RegisterStartupScript?

Comment: @Dotnet did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes you can check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885123/javascript-with-in-stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

Code Behind

```
public partial class call_jquery_from_class_file : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Alert.ShowAlertMessage("Testing Code", Page);
}
}
```

Class file Code

```
public class Alert
{
public static void ShowAlertMessage(string error, Page page)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {");
    sb.AppendLine("    $(\"form\").append($(\"<div>\").attr(\"id\", \"dialog\").css(\"display\", \"none\").html('"+error+"'));");
    sb.AppendLine("    $(\"#dialog\").dialog({autoOpen: true,show: \"blind\",hide: \"explode\" });");
    sb.AppendLine("});");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", sb.ToString(), true);
}
}
```

Hope it helps you,.

Same is working for me.That's why i suggested same.

Comment: Hi I need to do as per the example http://jquerymsgbox.ibrahimkalyoncu.com/ I tried this in convertion but didn't worked can u help me out

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Button control has Attributes property. So if you want to call javascript method on server control you just need to add "onclick" Attribute. For example you have btnAlert control:

**Javascript file:**

```
function example1(title, content) {
    $.msgBox({
        title: title,
        content: content
    });
}
```

**ASP.NET code behind in Page Load:**

```
btnAlert.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Format("example1('{0}', '{1}'); return false;", "some title", "some message"));
```

You should add return false to prevent PostBack. BTW If you need a control only for calling client side methods you may use general html control(`<button onclick='example1("<%= Resources.Title %>", "<%= Resources.Content %>")'>Example button</button>`) and add your title and content by using `<%= %>`.